# Accessing Sandbox leads in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, sandbox, marketing-cloud-connect

We have a sandbox account and a marketing cloud account. We have installed marketing cloud connected app in sandbox and installed marketing cloud connect package.

There are few leads in sandbox which we want to access/sync in marketing cloud. How can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the connector has been configured correctly (otherwise please follow [these steps](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_connect_the_clouds.htm&type=5)), you should be able to create your Lead object as a Synchronised Data Extension, in Contact Builder > Data Sources of the Business Unit where the connection has been established:

> 1. Select the data source connected via account integration on the **Synchronized** tab.
> 2. Click **Set Up Object**.
> 3. Click **Synchronize** for the entity containing the data to bring into Contact Builder.
> 4. Select the checkboxes next to the fields to synchronize and click **Next**.
> 5. Choose whether to bring in all records or begin at a certain date using the **Records Collection** buttons.
> 6. Choose how often you wish the synchronize data in the **Poll Schedule** dropdown menu.
> 7. Click **Save & Synchronize**.

Find recommended best practices for Synchronised Data Sources in [this document](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_implement_synchronized_data_sources_best_practices.htm&type=5).